Permutations Required to Randomly sort a deck
Let $ D_n =\{s \in \mathbb{N}_{1} | s<n\} $ (a deck of n>1 cards).
Assuming you 'shuffle' using a single transposition $(i,j)$ that is, you take the card in the ith place and swap it with the jth one where $i \neq j$
For $D_n$ how many shuffles $s_n$ are required before the deck is random?
My definition of random is the probability of any card being in any position is 1/n.
My Solution
$s_n=n-1$
Proof $s_2=1$ the first transposition has a 0.5 chance at being the identity and 0.5 chance at not
Assume true for n
Consider $D_{n+1}=D_n \cup \{n+1\} $ now consider an n+1-shuffle that is $(i_1,j_1)...(i_{n},j_{n})$ rewrite this transposition as follows:
$(n+1,k)(i'_{n-1},j'_{n-1})...(i'_1,j'_1)$
As the r.h.s of the transposition list is an n length shuffle on $D_n$ so random and the l.h.s puts the n+1th element in a random position therefore $s_n$ infers $s_{n+1}$ and induction
I have two questions:
1.) Is the proof valid? I studied algebra not probability at uni so any glaring holes would be appreciated. (The l.h.s and r.h.s seems very off to me!)
2.) Is there something deeper going on here in terms of probabilities in $S_n$ and it's generators or is this question one more of pure probability?

In the case $n=2$ your condition $i\neq j$ actually ensures perfect predictability, i.e., the absence of randomness.

I don't get the question. Do we know what the position of the cards are before all the swaps? Surely then the sequence of swaps is deterministic, and so then what does it mean that, "the probablity... is $1/n$"?

Hi! Your first sentence implies $D_n = {2, 3, \ldots, n-1}$. Is this really what is intended? In general, I find formal notation more of a hindrance than a help, by and large, unless the formalism is actually needed for something. It might be clearer to just write it as $D_n = {1, 2, \ldots, n}$, for example, if that's what's intended.

More generally: To make this problem a bit more "approachable", I would introduce some metric that represents the difference between two distributions over the possible permutations, or at least the divergence of any given distribution from the uniform one. In general, I would expect this difference to start at some maximum value (since we begin with some deterministic initial permutation) and diminish toward $0$ without ever reaching it.

This question was asked on MO, and answered in the comments with a reference. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429774/random-permutations-constructed-via-randomly-chosen-transpositions

For any deck $D_n$, there are $n!$ permutations. So you "merely" have to roll an $n!$-sided fair die and use the result of the roll to choose a permutation. And if you want, you can express that permutation as a sequence of transpositions. But you'll have different lengths of sequences for odd and even permutations.

Alternative answer involving Markov chains.
You can represent the problem as a graph where the $n!$ permutations are the vertices and two vertices are linked by an arc labeled $\{i, j\}$ (unordered pair of distinct numbers) if one permutation is transformed into the other by swapping the elements $i$ and $j.$
Now imagine a random process that starts at the vertex representing the original order of the deck, and every second it jumps with equal probability to any of the $n(n-1)/2$ neighbouring vertices. This is you carrying out a single shuffle.
The probability distribution of the vertices after $k$ steps starts from a $100$ percent peak at a single vertex for $k=0$ and gradually flows out over a larger part of the graph as $k$ increases (with the limitation that the permutation is always even or odd depending whether $k$ is even or odd), but however large a finite even value of $k$ you choose, the probability never becomes uniform over all even permutations, and the original order always retains a slightly higher-than-average probability among all even permutations.

Markov chains are probably the answer I wanted. Really nice answers thanks a lot! Just goes to show one's intuition of a truly random deck of cards is never truly a thing

I am assuming that you suppose a uniform probability distribution on the swaps $(i j).$
If you maintain the condition $i\neq j$ then a deck of $2$ cards is never random because there is only one swap available: after an even number of shuffles the initial order is restored, while after an odd number of shuffles it is reversed. And in the $n=3$ case after only $n-1=2$ swaps there is a probability of $1/9$ that the first card is not affected at all, and a probability $2/9$ that the first swap involves the first card but the second swap reverses it; so we have a probability of $1/3$ that the original order remains in place, which is more than the $1/6$ uniform probability distribution over all possible permutations.
Dropping the $i\neq j$ condition requires you to specify whether not swapping anything deserves the same probability as any single swap or $n$ times that probability (counting each "swap" (i i) separately). But either way it is unlikely to generate a uniform distribution after a finite number of swaps. Most of the intuitive choices of probability distributions would tend to result in a probability to remain in the original position that is higher than the average probability of all permutations.
One "hard" limitation of your $i\neq j$ shuffle is that the permutations on a set of $n$ elements can be divided into two equally-sized disjoint subsets called even and odd permutations. A swap of two elements is an odd permutation. A composition of an even number of swaps is always even while a composition of an odd number of swaps is always odd. So at best, you could hope to achieve randomness among all even permutations or among all odd permutations, never both.
